# TypeError: app.listen is not a function NODEJS

Tags: node.js, function, listen

I cant understand why I see this error.

my `app.js` file

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require('morgan');
const app = express();

const tourRouter = require('./routers/tourRouter');
const userRouter = require('./routers/userRouter');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    req.RequestTime = new Date().toISOString();
    next();
});

app.use('/api/v1/tours',tourRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/users',userRouter);
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

this runs without a problem, but when I cut

```
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

this part and I write app.js folder exports.module = app;
and I create `server.js` file

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});
```

this doesn't work and I get

> TypeError: app.listen is not a function

Comment: wrong code, `app` variable is is assumed for express not for your own module, you need to require express again in server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Dickens A S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4489164/dickens-a-s) commented, you need to assign the `object: app: instance of express` to the `module.exports` in the `file: "app.js"`.

Read Doc: [Node.js: module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports)

> many want their module to be an instance of some class. To do this, assign the desired export object to module.exports.

Add this in the of of `file:app.js`:

`module.exports = app;`

Answer (score 0):

for this to work you must export the module so add:

```
module.exports = app
```

in your `app.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and I had to resolve it with destructuring in the require statement.

Of course, at the bottom of `app.js`:

```js
module.exports = { app }
```

And then at the top of `server.js`:

```js
const { app } = require('./app')
```

I was getting the same `TypeError` when I was trying to require it like this:

```js
const app = require('./app')
```